# Convert HTML text into plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a method or function that does this, or do I have to check each character of a string. To give an idea on what I'm talking about, for example. I have an HTML TEXT like:

```
<p><strong>Welcome&nbsp;</strong>to this&nbsp;<em>message,&nbsp;</em><span style="text-decoration: underline;">you may come in peace.</span></p>
```

I need to convert it into a plain text, resulting into:

```
Welcome to this message, you may come in peace.
```

The text will come from a textarea which is a child of a `div` with an `id = editor-email`.

I also wanted to take the current text, but it won't work.

```
var textEmail = $('#editor-email').find('textarea').text();
```

Comment: ```
html = "<p><strong>Welcome&nbsp;</strong>to this&nbsp;<em>message,&nbsp;</em><span style="text-decoration: underline;">you may come in peace.</span></p>"
html = html.replace(/<style([\s\S]*?)<\/style>/gi, '');
html = html.replace(/<script([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, '');
html = html.replace(/<\/div>/ig, '\n');
html = html.replace(/<\/li>/ig, '\n');
html = html.replace(/<li>/ig, '  *  ');
html = html.replace(/<\/ul>/ig, '\n');
html = html.replace(/<\/p>/ig, '\n');
html = html.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, "\n");
html = html.replace(/<[^>]+>/ig, '');
console.log(html)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like with pure JS

```js
let a = `<p><strong>Welcome&nbsp;</strong>to this&nbsp;<em>message,&nbsp;</em><span style="text-decoration: underline;">you may come in peace.</span></p>
`;

let d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHTML = a;
console.log(d.innerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
$("p").text()
```

EDIT:

If you want the value from the textarea then you will need:

```
$("#editor-email > textarea").val();
```

Comment: this wont work if you have more than one <p> element

Comment: What if it's a textarea, I'll update my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @JanArielSanJose If its a textarea then do $("textarea").val()

Comment: @KeesdeWit look at the updated question, it's a child of a div. I can't make it seem to work.

Comment: @JanArielSanJose Check my update

Comment: @KeesdeWit I can't still get it. I'm trying to use `alert` to debug. This is what happened to the line.

`var textEmail = $("#editor-email > textarea").text();`

Comment: @KeesdeWit Oh wait, I forgot to change text to val. 

Now I changed it and it returns "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a JQuery-free solution, you can select the element and use `.innerText`:

```
document.querySelector('#myElement').innerText
```

Comment: This will not work for old browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Comment: querySelector will not, but selecting the element isn't the pertinent part